# Don't understand flow of contril

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Messages {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        message1();
        message2();
        System.out.println("Done with main.");
    }

    public static void message1() {
        System.out.println("This is message1.");
    }

    public static void message2() {
        System.out.println("This is message2.");
        message1();
        System.out.println("Done with message2.");
    }   
}
```

Why does this print out `Done with message2` first although the `message1` function is called first?

Comment: Show the output

Comment: Because _message2()_ is calling from the main method before "Done with main." line will be printed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not answer my question.  I asked why the code prints out "This is message2" (not "Done with message2") as the first line of output.  Can you please explain the flow from beginning to end?  Thank you!

Comment: *"as the first line of output"* It doesn't. If it does for you, then you're not running the code you've posted.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  When I ran the code in Eclipse, the output pane scrolled up so that I couldn't see the first line of output.  The first line of output that I could see was "This is message2".  My sincere apologies.  I am new to Eclipse and Java.  Now I know to be mindful of the the up/down arrows on the right.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Why does this print out `Done with message2` first?

It doesn’t. On my computer your program prints:

```
This is message1.
This is message2.
This is message1.
Done with message2.
Done with main.
```

I suspect your problem is lying somewhere else.

Comment: [Are "Your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923). Write a comment that the question is unclear and flag it as unclear, instead of writing an "answer", we currently don't know what we have to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Learning all the time.